# React Native's KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset overlaps underline on textinput

Tags: android, react-native

I am using keyboardVerticalOffset in order to move content up appropriately when the keyboard is displayed. It is working well, however the underline is covered up when the keyboard is displayed.

If I increase the keyboardVerticalOffset value it just adds white space below the input, and you still can't see the underline.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
  style={{ 
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'column', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }} 
  behavior="padding" 
  keyboardVerticalOffset={90}
  enabled>
   ScrollView 
     style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}} 
     keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
      <Content style={globalStyles.content} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
        <Form>
          {this.renderInspectionDetails()}
          {this.renderClientInformation()}
          {this.renderBuyersAgentDetails()}
          {this.renderSellersAgentDetails()}
          {this.renderNotes()}
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

The following image displays a text input focused.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I'd like to understand this too.

Comment: Would love to see an answer to this.